# BIB-file not editable in Overleaf (due to size?)

Tags: overleaf

Here, it is hard to provide an MWE, since the problem seems to evolve when BIB files are a bit larger.

However, when I try to edit a comparatively large BIB-file in Overleaf

It looks like this:
[image]
That is, I can not edit the BIB file, only download it and edit it on the harddrive and then upload it again.

The size of my bib file:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance,
Lars

Comment: Few people here will be able to answer this question. You should probably ask at the Overleaf support.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Hi Lars, yes, there is a threshold for file size in order for the file to be editable. If the file is above a certain size, we flag it as not editable to conserve editor resources (and most .bib files this large are auto-generated by a reference manager anyway). If you need to work around this, you can split the large .bib file into two smaller chunks and upload the two separately. Then each file will be editable on its own, and you can update your .tex code to point to the two .bib files instead of the single larger file.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks! Exactly how large is that threshold? Good for knowing how to make the splitting.

Comment: @PaulGessler does that mean changing `\bibliography{central}` to `\bibliography{central1,central2}` for example?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you. This time, I seemed to be lucky. However, for the future, do you have the URL to that support page?

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson I've never tried, but if I would, I'd bet at https://www.overleaf.com/contact

Comment: Yes, that's the way for bibtex (with biblatex I would recommend multiple `\addbibresource` macros instead). The limits are roughly 2 MB but there may be slightly different thresholds depending on how we receive the file (web upload, direct editing online, Dropbox, Git, GitHub). Unfortunately we have some different limits set in various areas for some historical reasons. But the "official" limits are documented here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_is_the_maximum_compilation_time,_file_number_and_project_size_allowed_on_free_vs_paid_plans%3F